# Lightning Component Testing Code Coverage

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, salesforcedx, slds, jasmine

I need some help here with lightning component testing. So I'd been building lightning component test on Salesforce using Jasmine testing framework. I was wondering if anyone here successfully implemented code coverage report on this instead of just doing unit testing for the sake of unit testing? I am planning to integrate Karma or Istanbul to do that, but it gets really tricky when I tried importing those libraries as static resource. It would be a tremendous help if anyone can share what they'd done so far to get a clearer coverage report using Jasmine framework.

I am hoping to generate a code coverage report like this:
[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently in the same boat. I have everything setup perfectly for our project, and this is the last piece. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ended up using this. https://github.com/aheber/sfdx-coverage But moving forward, we are going to use Jest in LWC since it provides line coverage.